# What is the best way to stack parafilm wrapped petri dishes?

Tags: lab-techniques, sterilisation, germination

I have several petri dishes that are individually wrapped with bemis parafilm.  As space is somewhat limited, I've begun stacking them on top of each other, however in doing this the wrapping for each plate will sometimes get stuck to the wrapping on the other plates.  Is there a good technique or separator or tool or something I can use to both efficiently store my plates and not jeopardize their parafilm seal?

Comment: Thinner strips of parafilm.

Comment: Is a sheet pan rack/"speed rack" a possible option? Or would that take up too much space for the number you need?

Comment: Yea that would take up too much room.  If I had plenty of space, I would just have them all laid out.  Considering trying to use 6"x6" wax paper for hamburger meat to separate them.  Kind of need to vertically store them and access them daily to track growth progress.

Comment: Do you need to individually wrap them? We used to just store a stack of them in the plastic bag the stack came in, resealed with tape at the end.

Comment: Our lab uses food-wrapping-foil to seal agar petri dishes instead of parafin. We buy a rool at grocery store an cut the rool with sharp knife into cca 1.3cm wide minirools which we than use. It is cheaper than parafin and food-wrap comes sterile from production. Never had problem with plates sticking to each other when stacked.

Comment: Guess it depends on how long you need to store them. Sometimes I've put them in a refrigerator-sized plastic tupperware container with a sealing lid. Didn't last quite as long as parafilm, but kept them from drying out long enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting the 6"x6" wax paper for hamburger meat and putting a sheet between stacked and wrapped petri dishes which prevented them from sticking to each other.  Their footprint is now bigger but it works.  I could cut the sheets down or probably get smaller ones if I really wanted though.

Above there are some interesting other solution suggested like saran wrap and other methods of storing them that may work for some other use case.  As I need to document my dishes progress regularly they get handled at least daily so 'extra' or a thick application parafilm is used to make sure they stay tightly sealed.